# Keeping Session in PowerShell After Restarting

Tags: python, powershell

I am working on PowerShell and is there any way to go back to the previous session after I restart it? I am programming
Python with it and it gets a bit tedious to go to the directory I am working every time I start PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting a home directory in your profile. Type `$profile` in your shell to find the path to your Powershell profile. Open this file in a text editor and add this line

```
Set-Location C:\Python\MyProject
```

Make sure its the first line, then every time you open Powershell it will Change its directory to the one you set in the profile. NOTE: This will not work if you're launching powershell with the -noprofile switch.

Comment: Where should I save that text file in?

Comment: You save it to your Powershell profile, which is located by entering `$profile` into your shell